# Dynamic styling and AoT compilation

Tags: angular, sass, angular2-aot

I'm currently working on a massive website with three different stylesheets (basically color changes). After AoT compilation, I want my UI to dynamically switch to one of those stylesheets.
So far, I can get the parameter which indicates what stylesheet to use but I have no idea how to implement this switch in the compiled version.
Don't know if I am clear enough (hope so), this is similar to a kind of "user-preference-theme-switching" thing.

I use:

- angular 4.0.0
- bootstrap 4.0.0-alpha.5
- material 2.0.0-beta.3
  Along with SASS.

Thanks a lot for any idea/suggestion!

Alex

Comment: This is a very broad question and not related to AoT.. You should be able to define multiple themes in angular material. However I wouldn't recommend combing it with bootstrap if you want a single theme provider.

Comment: Hi Raven, thanks for your comment. If I understand, you suggest to implement that at root component level? My first guess was to work at a lower level, something like hacking the src/styles.scss file...